# Cannot find module './BrowserFetcher.js'

Tags: javascript, npm, puppeteer

I just upgraded all my npm packages, and when trying to run on my local host, I am getting the error that

```
Error: Cannot find module './BrowserFetcher.js'
```

This particular error is pointing to this line in my puppeteer file, which is located at - /Users/Kyle/Scanning/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js

```
const BrowserFetcher_js_1 = require("./BrowserFetcher.js");
```

Update: ./BrowserFetcher.js is not in the npm package (I had overlooked). How can I import? Should it not already come with puppeteer?

Comment: Can you share your dependencies in `package.json`? Also you can try imporrting the file without the extension, ie. `require('./BrowserFetcher')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are using the [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) NPM package, based on the route you've shared in your error stack:

```
/Users/Kyle/Scanning/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js
```

This package doesn't have any `'BrowserFetcher'` module exported, so attempting to `require()` or `import` it will fail.

Per [their docs](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v7.1.0), a minimal example of usage would be:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });

  await browser.close();
})();
```

On the other hand, `BrowserFetcher` seems to belong to the [puppeteer-sharp](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp) project, which is a C# package, not a Javascript/Node.js one.